# JQuery autocomplete apparently recognizing but not displaying select options

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a problem with jQuery UI autocomplete. I think it comes from the source file (remote file named places.php ), but it is a little strange : this source is correctly json encoded, with no white space in its beginning (I thought this could be the problem, but it is not) and works fine when I directly access it in the browser. For instance, for the term ‘u’ it will return

```
(places.php)

[{"id":"2","place":"Belgium"},{"id":"1","place":"USA"}]
```

The problems come when I try to access the datas indirectly with this form :

```
<label for="the_value" value="">Value</label>
<input type="text" id="the_value" name="the_value" value=""/>         
<input type="hidden" id="the_id" name="the_id" value="default"/>
```

When the user types something in ‘the_value’ input box, the values from places.php should appear. Instead, the sliding panel opens for only 2 to 3 millimeters and displays nothing… (it seems that, even if no options are displayed, the script recognized they were available because it move a bit, which does not happen when not results exist …). Note: this problem is not browser related: it appears both in mozilla and IE8.
The javascript is the following

```
$(function(){
    $('#the_value').autocomplete({
        source : 'places.php',       
        select : function(event, ui){
            $('#the_id').val(ui.item.id);  
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your JSON file is being sent with an "application/json" content type?

Comment: Hi mblase75, yes I did. thank you for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the jQuery UI documentation:

> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains
>   Objects for each item in the array, with either a label or value
>   property or both. The label property is displayed in the suggestion
>   menu. The value will be inserted into the input element after the user
>   selected something from the menu.

If you change `place` to `value`, the plugin will know what to display in the dropdown, but you will still be able to access `id` in the select handler.

Answer (score 1):

From [jQuery's autocomplete documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains
>   Objects for each item in the array, with either a label or value
>   property or both. The label property is displayed in the suggestion
>   menu. The value will be inserted into the input element after the user
>   selected something from the menu. If just one property is specified,
>   it will be used for both, eg. if you provide only value-properties,
>   the value will also be used as the label.

Basically it's either an array, or if it's json, it needs to have "value" and/or "label" where value is the set value in your input element and label is the displayed value. If only "value" or "label" is present then they are used for both.